# Using anti forgery token to prevent CSRF attacks with jQuery-3.2.1 in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
    function GetRequestVerificationToken() {
    var token = $('input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]').val();
    var headers = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    return headers;
}
```

I have the above GetRequestVerificationToken() function that i have been using in my Ajax calls in asp.net MVC 3 application with jquery-1.7.2.

After upgrading to jquery-3.2.1, i get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]
>       at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:1580)
>       at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:2232)
>       at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:2659)
>       at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:884)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:2922)
>       at jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:3032)
>       at jQuery (jquery-3.2.1.js?v=2017_1:98)
>       at GetRequestVerificationToken (Common.js?v=2017_1:265)
>       at setCalender (Report.js?v=2017_1:81)
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):967)

Any one know what syntax changes i need to make?

Below is my sample usage script

```
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: { startDate: sdate, endDate: edate },
            headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Test/List',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#DivAction").html(data);
                TableSorter('audit');
                HideLoader();
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("err in Audit Trail Search");
                HideLoader();
            }
```

Comment: did you solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resoloved the issue was re-writing my GetRequestVerificationToken function as below.

```
function GetRequestVerificationToken() {
//var token = $('input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]').val();
var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
var headers = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
return headers;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$('input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]')
```

to this:

```
$('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')
```

All information you need is shown in the error message.